# Bidirectional HTTP tunnel over a file/pipe

Tags: bash, http, socat

I have a remote machine that I can get a shell into but can't do port forwarding, so everything has to go over stdin/stdout through the shell process. There's an HTTP server on the remote machine that I would like to connect to using a browser on my local machine.

What I've tried is the following:

```
mkfifo /tmp/socattunnel
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:12345,crlf,reuseaddr,fork - </tmp/socattunnel | remote_shell -- socat - TCP:localhost:6006 2>/dev/null >/tmp/socattunnel
```

The idea is to run one socat instance on my local machine, listening on port 12345, and one instance running on the remote machine connects to the existing HTTP server running on port 6006. The local instance reads from a named pipe and writes to the remote shell, which writes back to the pipe, completing the cycle.

With this setup, I can do `curl http://localhost:12345` on my local machine and it works fine, but if I try to run it again, I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. Here's the socat log:

```
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:12345,crlf,reuseaddr,fork - </tmp/socattunnel | remote_shell -- socat - TCP:localhost:6006 2>/dev/null >/tmp/socattunnel
2019/04/25 14:43:57 socat[46138] N listening on LEN=16 AF=2 0.0.0.0:12345
2019/04/25 14:44:01 socat[46138] N accepting connection from LEN=16 AF=2 127.0.0.1:57506 on LEN=16 AF=2 127.0.0.1:12345
2019/04/25 14:44:01 socat[46138] N forked off child process 46141
2019/04/25 14:44:01 socat[46138] N listening on LEN=16 AF=2 0.0.0.0:12345
2019/04/25 14:44:01 socat[46141] N reading from and writing to stdio
2019/04/25 14:44:01 socat[46141] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [0,1]
2019/04/25 14:44:02 socat[46141] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2019/04/25 14:44:02 socat[46141] N exiting with status 0
2019/04/25 14:44:02 socat[46138] N childdied(): handling signal 20
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46138] N accepting connection from LEN=16 AF=2 127.0.0.1:57507 on LEN=16 AF=2 127.0.0.1:12345
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46138] N forked off child process 46173
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46138] N listening on LEN=16 AF=2 0.0.0.0:12345
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46173] N reading from and writing to stdio
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46173] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [0,1]
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46173] E write(1, 0x7fde27004e00, 74): Broken pipe
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46173] N exit(1)
2019/04/25 14:44:05 socat[46138] N childdied(): handling signal 20
```

In particular: `E write(1, 0x7fde27004e00, 74): Broken pipe` in the second child.

I then tried to reproduce the problem without going over the remote shell, by using tee:

```
python3 -m http.server 6006 &
mkfifo /tmp/socattunnel
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:12345,crlf,reuseaddr,fork - </tmp/socattunnel | tee /dev/stderr | socat - TCP:localhost:6006 >/tmp/socattunnel
```

And this also runs into the same problem. Is there an alternative approach for creating a bidirectional HTTP tunnel over a file/pipe?

Comment: Found a (hacky) workaround by simply wrapping the entire thing in a loop instead of using the fork option, which allows for basic browsing: while True; do socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr - </tmp/socattunnel | create_shell -- socat - TCP:localhost:6006 2>/dev/null >/tmp/socattunnel; done

Comment: `can't do port forwarding` - so you mean `ssh -R` will not work. Create a `pppd` session. `ppp` uses only stdin/stdout with ssh. Downside is you have to do some forwarding, but it's stable.

Comment: @KamilCuk yep. Thanks for the pppd tip, will try that out. Would be nice if I could get it working on macOS as well, but a Linux solution would be a good start.

Comment: Looks like pppd is available on macOS too. Nice.